# Python: (IndexError: list index out of range) readFile

Tags: python, split, readfile

I got this text in a text file file:

```
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:3 , 13_
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:6 , 24_
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:8 , 33_
```

and I want to have it like this

```
_data=['2015.9.30 - 15:36:3', '2015.9.30 - 15:36:6', '2015.9.30 -15:36:8']_
_values=['13', '24', '33']_
```

so I tried this code

```
def getData(path):
   data = []

   readFile = open(path,'r')
   sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
   readFile.close()

   for i in sepFile:
       myData = i.split(',')
       data.append(myData[0])

   return data



def getValues (path):
   values = []

   readFile = open(path,'r')
   sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
   readFile.close()

   for i in sepFile:
       myValues = i.split(',')
       values.append(myValues[1])

   return values

print getData("mytext.txt")
print getValues("mytext.txt")
```

---

the first method getData works fine but the second one dont want to work ..
errormessage:

```
['2015.9.30 - 15:36:3 ', '2015.9.30 - 15:36:6 ', '2015.9.30 - 15:36:8'] 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\z.NEW\schrottplatz.py", line 34, in <module>
print getValues("mytext.txt")
File "C:\Python27\z.NEW\schrottplatz.py", line 29, in getValues
values.append(myValues[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: are the `_` really part of your data?

Comment: Check if you have a comma in every line in your file. Does it maybe contain empty lines, e.g. at the very end? The error occurs when the program tries to split a string containing no commas, resulting in a list with only one value, meaning that index 1 does not exist in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.txt

```
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:3 , 13_
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:6 , 24_
_2015.9.30 - 15:36:8 , 33_
```

code

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

_data, _values = [], []
for d in data:
    val = d.split(' , ')
    _data.append(val[0][1:])
    _values.append(val[1][:-1])

print _data
print _values
#['2015.9.30 - 15:36:3', '2015.9.30 - 15:36:6', '2015.9.30 - 15:36:8']
#['13', '24', '33']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, `_` are not parts of your file.

```
2015.9.30 - 15:36:3 , 13
2015.9.30 - 15:36:6 , 24
2015.9.30 - 15:36:8 , 33
```

Using generators, a solution would be like this :

```
with open(path) as f:
    data, values = zip(*(line[:-1].split(" , ") for line in f.readlines()))
```

If `_` are part of  your file, then the following will also work :

```
with open(path) as f:
    data, values = zip(*(line[1:-2].split(" , ") for line in f.readlines()))
```